# Armbian Kernel Compilation Issue

Tags: compiler-errors, arm, kernel, orange-pi

I am looking to prepare kernel headers on orange pi plus

kernel version  4.14.68-sunxi
Release Bionic

Command : cd /usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.68-sunxi && sudo make scripts -j4

Result:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:155: recipe for target 'scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s' failed
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:587: recipe for target 'scripts/mod' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
Makefile:569: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```

I have tried everything

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The actual error message(s) (which is useful for debug the problem) is somewhere above given lines. Also, for debugging the error it is better to run `make` **without** `-j` option. Do that, and show actual error message.

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xbPqBuMCPSEZp6RbvH-iPpDE6Vd0d7_s/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: No, no needs in using `--debug` option for `make` - its output is useful only when debug the Makefile itself, otherwise it produces tons of output which is unneeded. Just run `make scripts` from the appropriate directory and with appropriate priviledges.